# document.getElementById + regex

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Can `document.getElementById` be used along with a regular expression?

For example an id on one page will be *Product-1* while on another page it will be *product-3*. (Don't aks me why but it cannot be changed apparently.)

What I would like to do is run a `getElementById` looking for an Id of *Product-x* where *x* is either 1 or 3.

Currently I have something like this:

```
var _container = document.getElementById("product-1") || document.getElementById("product-3");
```

which works - but I wonder if there is a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are _awesome_ for this.

Comment: Strip the jQuery from the jQuery and get Sizzle, jQuery's selector engine: http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: +1 but if you're going to be doing _cool stuff_ like this, jQuery might help in other areas as well.  Multi-purpose FTW.  Ockham's Razor @Blender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getElementById base on partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string)

Answer (score 27):

Yep. document.querySelectorAll seems to be good here.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=product]')
```

Borrowed from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string)

MDN Link [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 10):

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are *awesome* for this.

An great example would be the "[starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector like so `$("*[id^=product]")`

Answer (score 1):

so you cant change the id of the elements but can you add a class?
if you add the class product to all your products you can get them
all by

```
document.getElementsByClassName("product")
```

and take the first one

Comment: Although this is nice & clean it is incompatible with IE 5.5, 6, 7 & 8. (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).  Instead I would recommend trying this => http://pastie.org/2574711