# How can I determine with one GetElementByID the unique id of different elements

Tags: javascript, html

for my different elements i have the same class tag with only different ending.
My html elements;

```
id="inner-main-container-one"
id="inner-main-container-two"
id="inner-main-container-three"
```

My code define in js is:

```
var content = document.getElementByID('inner-main-container-one');
var contentone = document.getElementByID('inner-main-container-two');
var contenttwo = document.getElementByID('inner-main-container-three');
```

How can i determine the unique id with one define ? Like this:

```
var content = document.getElementByID('inner-main-container-%%');
```

Comment: That's not a class _or_ a tag. It's an ID attribute.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'd have to run a loop over an array of suffixes.

Comment: Chick this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061760/document-getelementbyid-regex

Comment: If you're going to use numbers, then use *numbers* - `inner-main-container-1`. That way you can loop through them (`for(i=0...`).

Comment: Okay, I have now built a loop and I get all the elements out. Unfortunately, I cannot execute an instruction with button.onclick when the element is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll('[id|=inner-main-container]');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to make adjustments to the HTML element? The output of content is namely empty.

Comment: How can i use it to check if some ID got clicked ? I have always queried this for individual objects with content.onclick. - but it doesnt function.

Comment: Use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on the NodeList. `content.forEach((node, index) => { node.onclick = ... })`

Comment: I dont know, exactly whats wrong

`const content = document.querySelectorAll('[id|=inner-main-container-button]');
content.forEach((node, index) => {
  node.onclick = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  }
});`

And i have different divs: 
`<div class="main-inner-container-button-1" id="main-inner-container-button-1">
<div class="main-inner-container-button-2" id="main-inner-container-button-2">`

Comment: You changed the order of the words in the `id` from your original post. So you need to update your selector: `[id|=main-inner-container-button]`.

Comment: Thanks
But now I have a similar problem. After clicking one of these elements I also want to make sure that the className is queried exactly from the clicked element & I can change this if a certain className applies.

Code:
`const button = document.querySelectorAll('[id|=main-inner-container-button]');
const content = document.querySelectorAll('[id|=main-inner-container-inner]')
button.forEach((node, index) => {
  node.onclick = function(){
    if(content.className.contains('open')) {
      console.log('open');
    }
  }
});`
Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'contains')

Comment: `content` refers to the entire [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). In your forEach function, the first argument refers to the individual node. So you'll want `if (node.className.contains('open')) { ...`

Comment: Okay, but the error still the same: Uncaught TypeError: node.className.contains is not a function  

`button.forEach((node, index) => {
  node.onclick = function(){
    if(node.className.contains('open')) {
      console.log('open');`

Comment: okay i got now a way. But how can i check, if the `node.className` contains open or not and attach open to the className ?

`if(node.className === '[id|=main-inner-container-button open]') {
      node.className= '[id|=main-inner-container-button]';
    } else {
      node.className='[id|=main-inner-container-button open]';
    }`

Comment: Okay, I have now resolved all issues and it works as expected. Thank you again!